# Creating indicator column based on conditional categorizing of rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
user.id  user_type
3          old
3          old
4          new
5          new
5          new
6          old
```

I want to create new column that would indicate the first time user_type is 'new' for each user_id.

Output should look like this:

```
user.id  user_type  indicator
3          old         2
3          old         2
4          new         1
5          new         1
5          new         2
6          old         2
```

I used transform function but it is not working, my code:

```
input <- transform(input, user =
ifelse(head(user_type) == "NEW", 1, 2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use one of the aggregating functions.  Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(input)`), grouped by 'user.id', we create an 'indicator' variable by checking the elements in 'user_type' that are 'new' (`user_type=='new'`) and at the same time meets the condition that it is the first observation (`(1:.N)==1L`)), negate it (`!`) to change 'TRUE' to 'FALSE' and viceversa, add 1 (i.e. `1L`) so that the TRUE gets converted to 2 and FALSE to 1.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(input)[,indicator:= (!((user_type=='new') & (1:.N)==1L))+1L, by= user.id]
#     user.id user_type indicator
#1:       3       old         2
#2:       3       old         2
#3:       4       new         1
#4:       5       new         1
#5:       5       new         2
#6:       6       old         2
```

Or using `dplyr`, we group by 'user.id', create a new column ('indicator') with `mutate` and `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)
input %>% 
    group_by(user.id) %>% 
    mutate(indicator= ifelse(user_type =='new' & row_number()==1L , 1, 2))
#   user.id user_type indicator
#1       3       old         2
#2       3       old         2
#3       4       new         1
#4       5       new         1
#5       5       new         2
#6       6       old         2
```

#### EDIT

I assumed previously that if the 'new' value is the first element of 'user_type' for each 'user.id', then it should be '1' and otherwise '2'.  If the OP wanted to get '1' for the first time 'new' occurs for each 'user.id' and not based on the first row.

```
  setDT(input)[, indicator:= (!(user_type=='new'& 
                 !duplicated(user_type)))+1L , user.id]
  #   user.id user_type indicator
  #1:       3       old         2
  #2:       3       old         2
  #3:       4       new         1
  #4:       5       new         1
  #5:       5       new         2
  #6:       6       old         2
```

If we change the 'user_type' as 'new' for the 2nd observation

```
  input$user_type[2] <- 'new'
  setDT(input)[, indicator:= (!(user_type=='new'& 
                      !duplicated(user_type)))+1L , user.id]
  #    user.id user_type indicator
  #1:       3       old         2
  #2:       3       new         1
  #3:       4       new         1
  #4:       5       new         1
  #5:       5       new         2
  #6:       6       old         2
```

using `dplyr`

```
  input %>% 
     group_by(user.id) %>% 
     mutate(indicator= ifelse(user_type=='new'&!duplicated(user_type), 1, 2))
```

#### data

```
input <- structure(list(user.id = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L),
user_type = c("old", 
"old", "new", "new", "new", "old")), .Names = c("user.id", "user_type"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I used this, input <- setDT(input)[,indicator:= (!((user_type=="NEW") & (1:.N)==1L))+1L, USER.ID] and getting error.  Error in `[.tbl_df`(setDT(input), , `:=`(indicator, (!((user_type == "NEW") &  : 
  object 'USER.ID' not found

Comment: @DheerajSingh I updated with the data used.  BTW, the `USER.ID` and `user.id` are different

Comment: NO, they are same. In my input file, it is stored as USER.ID , here I wrote as user.id while citing an example. I changed user.id to USER.ID while running.

Comment: @DheerajSingh Okay, in that case, i was mistaken.  Can you try with the data I used.  Based on the Error, it is `USER.ID not found`, I think there is some problem in changing the column names.

Comment: Anyways, with using dplyr it is giving right output. It would be of great help if you could explained the code you used using data.table

Comment: @DheerajSingh Are you saying that you are still not getting it correct with data.table using my data

Comment: with your data, it is giving fine result.

Comment: @DheerajSingh  I noticed that you are using `tbl_df`, convert it to data.frame first and try it. i.e. `as.data.frame(input)` or use `as.data.table(input)`.  I updated with some explanations.

Comment: @DheerajSingh I have a doubt regarding your question.  Suppose, if `input$user_type[2] <- 'new'`, would you take that as `1` for the indicator?  In that case, David Arenburg's solution is correct.  I read the question if the first element in 'user_type' for each 'user.id' is 'new', then `1` should be assigned.

Comment: @DheerajSingh updated the post so that now you can get 1 for user_type 'new' even if the position is not first.

Answer (score 3):

Another `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[match("new", user_type)], by = user.id]$V1
df[indx, indicator := 1L][is.na(indicator), indicator := 2]
#    user.id user_type indicator
# 1:       3       old         2
# 2:       3       old         2
# 3:       4       new         1
# 4:       5       new         1
# 5:       5       new         2
# 6:       6       old         2
```

Comment: After re-reading the question, I think your solution may be the OP wanted.

Comment: @akrun not sure how is it different from yours, but as usual OP chose to ignore it :)

Comment: It will be different if `df$user_type[2] <- 'new'` because I thought if the first observation is 'new' then '1' and rest as `2`

Comment: @akrun I trust you that you figured it out :)